# „ab die Post“ explanation?

Tags: idiom

I’m trying to understand „ab die Post“ —  I know that it means something like “let’s get going“, but the question is why?

This page 
https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ab_die_Post

suggest that it originates from the highly efficient Thurn & Taxis postal system in 1490-1866, which makes me think the meaning is something like: “let’s move like something FROM the postal system!”   Is that the sense?

And why “ab”? Understanding little words like “ab” is a big problem for me.  If anyone has advice other than just “keep learning vocabulary” I’d be glad to hear it.

Comment: For the "ab": Think of English expression "off they go!", marking the starting moment. "off" is one possible meaning of "ab".

Comment: *Und ab die Post.* is not exactly *Let's get going.* but more like *Shift it!* (your butt).

Comment: I appreciate all the help with "ab", but no one has yet directly answered the part of my question about "die Post" (i.e., “'let’s move like something FROM the postal system!' Is that the sense?") Do German-speakers say this without even considering a connection to the postal system? I know people say idioms in English without understanding the connection (e.g., "in a pickle", "bone dry", "lower the boom", etc...)

Comment: Most simply: *einen Brief **ab**schicken*. Also: *Die Post geht ab* is a term for "the mail is being sent".  Therefore *Ab die Post*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volker is right in his comment with his translation: *"off they go"* means pretty much the same.
Now to the question why *ab* is used:
I think the *ab* is from *abgehen* in the meaning of *sich von etwas lösen/entfernen*, but in the idiom the *gehen* part is ommited. The word *abgehen* however is nowadays used with several different meanings:

- "Hier geht es ab" means that theres a lot happening
- "Der Sticker geht ab" means the sticker is falling off
- "Ab geht's!" has pretty much the same meaning as "Ab (geht) die Post"

Comment: If someone said “Ab geht die Post” would that sound synonymous to “Ab die Post“ to  a German speaker?

Comment: Mostly, yes. But (at least where I live) "Ab geht die Post" isn't used very often, and I guess that it's pretty close to something like "Hier geht die Post ab", which is pretty much synonymous to "Hier geht's ab". Therefor people may assume something different than the speaker intended. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Cp *pop goes the weasel* for the syntax at least. cp *hop-hop!* "hurry up", *auf-auf* "get up, let's go, get to it"

Answer (score 3):

This comes from the time where mail was carried by horses and/or carriage.  "Jetzt geht die Post ab" means that the rider or coach responsible for mail transport is departing.  Mail delivery was a strenuous business for both rider and horses, and motor carriages have substituted for them basically starting in the 20th century, a much too short period to change an idiomatic expression such as that.  And even when motor carriages did supplant mail transport by horse, it would have been done at a time when motor carriages were able to even surpass the already unusually high pace that the comparatively short-lived postal horses were traveling at.